# Importar dados com espaços dentro dos campos de um txt para o R

Tags: r, txt

Boa tarde

Gostaria de importar um arquivo, e postarei um exemplo para ser auxiliado
Ele é composto por nomes com separações de espaço e números

Para me ajudar na solução, gostaria por favor que copiasse essas informações para o Excel e para salvá-lo em txt separado por tabulações, ou em algum outro formato txt que resolva o problema

```
dados        numero     nome
rua joao     15         Joao Inep
rua maria    25         Maria Suiço
rua dois     35         Fernando José
```

Esse arquivo está no Excel, e ao salvá-lo em txt separado por tabulações e tentar importar para o R, há um problema em relação aos espaços existentes dentro de cada campo

Gostaria de um auxílio para importá-lo

tentei importar selecionando tudo no excel e usando o comando

```
dados<-read.table('clipboard', h=T)
```

também tentei usando o mesmo código

```
dados<-read.table(ENDEREÇO DO ARQUIVO NO MEU COMPUTADOR.TXT, h=T)
```

Desde já agradeço

Comment: Henrique, qual o código que você utilizou para importar o arquivo e qual como está o output com erro?

Comment: boa tarde, editei a pergunta com a informação, obrigado pela disponibilidade

Comment: Tente isso: `read.table(file, header = T, sep = "")`

Comment: 'Error in read.table("clipboard", h = T, sep = "") : 
            more columns than column names'

Informa esse erro descrito

Comment: Se rotineiramente precisa ler arquivos do Excel no R, experimente o pacote readxl: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/

Comment: obrigado pela indicação, porém eu gostaria de importar o arquivo através de um txt, contendo as informações descritas

Comment: Você salvou ele em do Excel para .txt como texto separado por tabulação? Se sim, isto aqui funcionou: `clipboard <- read.delim("C:/Users/BRENNER BIASI/Desktop/clipboard.txt")`

Comment: Resolvido, muito obrigado pelo auxílio, se quiser comentar como resposta para eu avaliar como solução para que você pontue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importando arquivo .txt a partir de arquivo de dados separados por tabulação em Excel.

```
clipboard <- read.delim("arquivo") # 
# arquivo = Endereço da pasta no computador + /nome do arquivo.txt
```

```
clipboard <- read.delim("C:/Users/BRENNER BIASI/Desktop/clipboard.txt")
```